# Inter-word spacing in long section heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I have a long section heading, e.g.

```
\subsubsection*{Identification Identification Identification Identification Identification Identification}
```

Using `chktex`, I got the warning "interword spacing (`\') should perhaps be used". But I don't know where to put the backslash.

Comment: You probably mean backslash ``\``, not forward slash `/`. However, this is just a suggestion, so if it doesn't seem necessary, you don't need to do it. Without seeing what the problem might be, it's difficult to address this question properly.

Comment: what that warning probably means (i've never used `chktex`) is that the spaces between words in the heading are wider than optimal.  this often happens when a heading runs to more than one line, and contains a lot of big, unhyphenatable words.  if it's not a run-in heading, i believe the best solution is to set it ragged, and get rid of all the spacing problems.  (ams editorial folk agree, and that's the way ams document classes are set up, at least the "derivative" ones for particular journals or book series.)  can't tell if that's your problem without an example.